# C#: downloading and attaching PDFs to MailMessage are corrupt

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, mailmessage

I am trying to first download a pdf as a string and then attach it to a `MailMessage`. Here is what I have done so far

```
string htmlAttachment = webClient.DownloadString((HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dictIterator.Value)));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(htmlAttachment);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment((Stream)stream, dictIterator.Key));
```

But whenever I open the pdf attachment, it says, `Insufficient data for an image'. Is it something related to encoding and should I directly download it as a stream rather than first getting it as`string`??

Comment: Downloading a binary file as string is most likely the problem.

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should download the file in Binary (**Not** as string.. No encoding involved.. Just pure binary).

---

PS - Try also saving the file locally to the disk, before attaching it. And then open it from the disk.
It will eliminate the **unlikely** possibility of `MailMessage` being the problem.